# Structure of $A(L)/A(K)$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry

Let $L/K$ be an extension of number fields and $A/K$ an abelian variety (or an elliptic curve, or a modular abelian variety).
Then what can we say about the structure of $A(L)/A(K)$ (or of $A(L)_{\text{tor}}/A(K)_{\text{tor}}$, or of $A(L)_{\text{non tor}}/A(K)_{\text{non tor}}$)?
Are there any researches?

For example, if $L$ is of exponent $2$ and if $A$ is the jacobian variety of a hyperelliptic curve, then we know that the prime to $2$ part of $A(L)$ is isomorphic to the one of $\oplus_\chi A^\chi(K)$.
(where the product takes all twist of $A/K$ over $L$.)

Comment: I doubt one can say much in this generality beyond simple representation theory. (Of course your statement for exponent $2$ generalises to split $A(L)\otimes \mathbb{Z}[1/\vert G\vert]$ when $L/K$ is Galois with group $G$). See $A(L)\otimes \mathbb{C}$ could be any representation of the Galois group $G$, probably, maybe, well this question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/280585/artin-representations-appearing-in-mordell-weil-groups-of-elliptic-curves hasn't been answered yet.